# Can we use any point for finding torque?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, torque

[image: here if we had tried to approach through finding torque about com, we would have landed to different answer.]I wanted to know whether we can find torque about any point?

For example consider a rolling disc with constant acceleration. We can find torque about instantaneous axis of rotation or about centre of mass. Which one of both will be due to friction, the constant force acting on the disc etc. But will they be equal? If not , then why? And how to decide which point to consider for finding torque.

One more thing why we can find torque about any point when net torque producing force on body is 0 :

Consider the question in the image :
Here if we had tried to approach through finding torque about centre of mass ,we would have landed to different answer

Comment: Please don't post photographs of text  which form the basis for your question. Retype the important parts . Also, rotated photographs, as in your post, are difficcult to read, and, frankly, not worth the effort. Please fix this.

Answer (score 3):

Torque can be defined relative to any point.  In a statics problem, you try to chose one which minimizes the number of torques. In a dynamics problem you are usually interested in the resulting rotation about an axis (perhaps instantaneous) or the center of mass of your object  (or system).

Comment: Thanks, brother but for example as you said in dynamics we can choose instantaneous axis or com for finding torque. Will they give same torque even when body is accelerating?

Comment: Changing the reference point changes the torque.  A single force acting off center on a free mass will cause a linear acceleration of the center of mass and an angular acceleration about the center of mass.

Comment: In statics, you can choose an arbitrary point _only because_ the sum of forces is zero. Otherwise, there would be an equipollent torque that you have to consider also.

Comment: In dynamics, the choice isn't arbitrary either. To decouple the equations of motion it is best to consider either the center of mass, or a fixed point. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Take an arbitrary point **A** and note the relationship between torque $\boldsymbol{\tau}_A$, change in  angular momentum $\tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} \boldsymbol{H}_A$, velocity of the body $\boldsymbol{v}_A$ and momentum $\boldsymbol{p}$

$$ \boldsymbol{\tau}_A = \tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} \boldsymbol{H}_A + \boldsymbol{v}_A \times \boldsymbol{p} $$

> <sub>Reference: [Equation 3.92, top of page 81](https://ethz.ch/content/dam/ethz/special-interest/mavt/mechanical-systems/mm-dam/documents/Notes/Dynamics_LectureNotes.pdf#page=85) of notes on dynamics, ETH Zurich.[image: eqref] [image: ICR]</sub>

Here at the conditions that have to be met for the last term to cancel

- Arbitrary point is fixed, $\boldsymbol{v}_A = 0$
- Arbitrary point at the instant centre of rotation during planar motion, $\boldsymbol{v}_A=0$
- Arbitrary point is co-moving with center of mass $\boldsymbol{v}_A = \boldsymbol{v}_{\rm COM}$
- Body is in pure rotation $\boldsymbol{p}=0$

So this is why typically dynamics is summed at the center of mass, at the pivot point or at the center of rotation. You can pick other points, but you have to be much more careful on how torques translate into rotational accelerations.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of torque as an analogous version of normal forces, but applied to rotating bodies. A normal traslational motion will be described, once you know all the forces and solve equations of motions, by the path $\vec{r}$ the object follows
$$
\vec{F}=\frac{d\vec{p}}{dt}\to \vec{r}=\vec{r}(t)
$$
Now when we are dealing with torque, we have a similar equation from which we want to know what the rotation will be: We are interested in knowing the rate of change of the angles of the object, let's say $\phi (t), \theta (t)$ and $\psi (t)$
$$
\vec{\tau _0} =\frac{d\vec{L_0}}{dt}\to \phi (t),\theta (t),\psi (t)
$$
Where I'm denoting the point from which you measure it as the subindex  $"0"$. But, of course, the angles that the object will described should not depend (and it doesn't) from the point from which you are measuring your torque, that would mean each observer is measuring a different movement!

What you are really changing when choosing your center, are the coordinates from which you are describing the movement. Even though that makes the equation look different, the physics behind for sure must be the same.

You can even choose and accelerating system of reference (typically a set of axis that rotates with the object) from which angular momentum looks really easy, and since the physics must be the same in all frames, you could transform it back to an inertial frame in which we are interested in describing the movement.